# PFUbiquityRecordsImporter - Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, icloud

I'm using iCloud with a library style sqllite core data project with mac and iOS apps. They sync all right except for 1 entity.

Single record created on ipad tried to download to mac with error:

> Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "completedDate";
>   desired type = NSDate; given type = __NSCFNumber; value = 0.
>   2011-12-02 18:19:58.175 Opus Domini[1653:403]
>   -_PFUbiquityRecordsImporter operation:failedWithError:: CoreData: Ubiquity:  Import operation ecountered an error: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "A Core Data error occurred."
>   UserInfo=0x10037a580 {exception=Unacceptable type of value for
>   attribute: property = "completedDate"; desired type = NSDate; given
>   type = __NSCFNumber; value = 0.} while trying to import the log file
>   at the URL:

Both projects share the same model and data classes, and other classes include Date fields with same parameters.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I turned out to be a simple mistake in my subclassed NSManagedObject for that entity. When merging iCloud logs, it uses the properties to set the data.